# How to find some possible combinations of pandas DataFrame given some constraints?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe, combinations

How to find all possible combinations of pandas DataFrame of size (m*n) given the following information:

- Combination size = n
- Each combination **MUST NOT** have more than one elements from the same row or column
  Example: for a DataFrame of size (3*2) with the data:

[image: DataFrame sample data]

we need to find all possible combinations of 2 elements where (1,4) is be a valid combination while as (1,2) or (1,3) are not valid because they contain elements from the same row or column

Answer (score 1):

This is an inefficient simple Implementation :)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1, 3, 5, 7], 'col2':[2, 4, 6, 8], 'col3':[9, 10, 11, 12]})
def get_all_combinations(dataframe, length):
    assert (len(dataframe.columns)>= length) & (len(dataframe)>= length)
    cols = list(itertools.combinations(dataframe.columns, length))
    rows = list(itertools.combinations(range(len(dataframe)), length))
    for col in cols:
        for row in rows:
            temp_df = dataframe.loc[row, col]
            print([temp_df.iloc[idx, idx] for idx in range(length)])
get_all_combinations(df, 2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4]
[1, 6]
[1, 8]
[3, 6]
[3, 8]
[5, 8]
[1, 10]
[1, 11]
[1, 12]
[3, 11]
[3, 12]
[5, 12]
[2, 10]
[2, 11]
[2, 12]
[4, 11]
[4, 12]
[6, 12]
```